# MongoDB - indexing for $or, $exists: false and sort queries

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Let's say I have the following document scehma:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('56f8c8ac1e80d48f16000007'),
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": {
        "c1": 31,
        "c2": 32
    },
    "d": 4,
    "e": 5
}
```

where `c2` does not always exists.

I need to query with an `$or` operator in addition to `$exists: false` on `'c.c2'` field and `sorting` on the `e` field.

This is how the query looks like:

```
db.test.find({
    $or : [
      {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
        'c.c1': 31,
        'c.c2': {$exists: false}
      },
      {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
        'd': 4
      }
    ]
}).sort({'e' : -1})
```

I have tried to create the following indexes:

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    'c.c1': 1,
    'c.c2': 1,
    e: 1
}, {name: 'test_1'}
```

AND

```
{
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    d: 1,
    e: 1
}, {name: 'test_2'}
```

When I use `explain()` on the query above I see it uses both of the indexes in parallel for the query stage, but it doesn't use the indexes for `sorting` which is the main problem.

If I change the `test_1` index to be without `c.c2` field and I remove this field with the `exists: false` from the query, I'm getting in the `explain()` exactly what I want: using of both indexes in parallel for the query stage, and using `SORT_MERGE` stage for merging both of the indexed queries.

But I need the `$exists: false` parameter, I have no idea how to index it correctly so it will use the `SORT_MERGE` stage after using the indexes on the indexed queries.

Comment: when you do $exists query, it queries meta information of element. so index won't work. It also depends on mongo version.  refer https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/ for more information.

Comment: Its better to have extra attribute saying c2_exists at top level. rather than doing $exists on attribute. you can add query like {c2_exists:true,.. }

Comment: @HariKrishnan so there is no solution for it except for adding another field which represents the existence of the c2 field. it's a basic concept of db's not to add fields if it they be represented by other fields, so it sounds strange. but thanks.

Comment: Or when you create index, create like below: db.collection_name.createIndex( { c.c2: 1 } , { sparse: true } ). when you query, db.collection_name.find().sort({"sort_key":-1}).hint({c.c2:1}). check whether this works for you. you can refer above mentioned url for more information

Comment: But I need the full query, not just this field if it exists or not. so if I'll use `hint` on this kind of index, it will be much slower